# How to place the add to cart button below description

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to place the add to cart button below description . I am tried many times but i am failed this is my addtocart.phtml file

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__(' BUY '); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <div class="qty-holder">
            <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
            <div class="qty-changer">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty_inc"><i class="icon-up-dir"></i></a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty_dec"><i class="icon-down-dir"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><i class="icon-cart"></i><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_block_id')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Now I want to place the add to cart button above price and availability like this in the image [image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Just move the code down?

Comment: i have tried but not working do u have any example @FabianBlechschmidt

Comment: What have you tried? What happend? What have you expected? Please edit your question instead of commenting, so it is far better readable.